# How to get EXM Manager Root programmatically?

Tags: exm

**Environment:** Sitecore 9.2 & SXA 1.8

**Scenario**: I have multiple `Manager Root` and also I have a created a custom message template including a couple of custom components that are being used in the email message body. I have added a custom field to the `Manager Root` template and would like to access this field in the custom components I have created. So how to get the parent Manager Root dynamically?

For Example, A field called "Current Company" added to the `Manager Root` template. In a custom component "Header", I want to get the value of this field.

How to achieve this functionality? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ManagerRootService class contains methods to get the data about EXM Manager Root.

You need to inject the **Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Services.ManagerRootService** into your class.

Looks like you need to use next method:

```
 public ManagerRoot GetManagerRootFromChildItem(Item childItem)
    {
      return this.GetManagerRootFromItem(ItemUtilExt.GetParentItemFromTemplate(childItem, "{CF9C8A2A-2794-4FEA-980A-EF8426F3D6C3}")) ?? this.GetManagerRootFromItem(childItem);
    }
```

Bellow is the **Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Services.ManagerRootService** methods:

```
public class ManagerRootService : IManagerRootService
  {
    private readonly ItemUtilExt _itemUtil;
    private readonly EcmSettings _exmSettings;

    public ManagerRootService(ItemUtilExt itemUtil, EcmSettings exmSettings)
    {
      Condition.Requires<ItemUtilExt>(itemUtil, nameof (itemUtil)).IsNotNull<ItemUtilExt>();
      this._itemUtil = itemUtil;
      this._exmSettings = exmSettings;
    }

    public List<ManagerRoot> GetManagerRoots()
    {
      string[] strArray;
      using (new SecurityDisabler())
      {
        Item obj = this._itemUtil.GetItem("{684CAA9A-FBD3-4FFB-891E-042E56B4E09C}");
        if (obj == null)
          throw new EmailCampaignException("The '{0}' item is not found.", new object[1]
          {
            (object) "{684CAA9A-FBD3-4FFB-891E-042E56B4E09C}"
          });
        strArray = obj["{9E4027B2-0360-4B48-B665-FC51E55FC766}"].Split(new char[1]
        {
          '|'
        }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
      }
      return ((IEnumerable<string>) strArray).Select<string, ManagerRoot>((Func<string, ManagerRoot>) (x => this.GetManagerRootFromId(Guid.Parse(x)))).Where<ManagerRoot>((Func<ManagerRoot, bool>) (root => root != null)).OrderBy<ManagerRoot, string>((Func<ManagerRoot, string>) (x => x.InnerItem.DisplayName)).ToList<ManagerRoot>();
    }

    public ManagerRoot GetManagerRootFromId(Guid rootId)
    {
      return this.GetManagerRootFromItem(this._itemUtil.GetItem(rootId));
    }

    public ManagerRoot GetManagerRootFromItem(Item item)
    {
      return this.GetCorrectManagerRootObject(item);
    }

    public ManagerRoot GetManagerRootFromChildItem(Item childItem)
    {
      return this.GetManagerRootFromItem(ItemUtilExt.GetParentItemFromTemplate(childItem, "{CF9C8A2A-2794-4FEA-980A-EF8426F3D6C3}")) ?? this.GetManagerRootFromItem(childItem);
    }

    public virtual ManagerRoot GetManagerRoot(Guid managerRootId)
    {
      return this.GetManagerRootFromItem(new ItemUtilExt().GetItem(new ID(managerRootId)));
    }

    public Guid CreateRoot()
    {
      using (new SecurityDisabler())
      {
        Item obj = this._itemUtil.AddItemFromBranch(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Email", "Email"), "{F8FAE92A-4F10-470C-AD5C-7ED9E6B636AF}", this._itemUtil.GetItem(this._exmSettings.GetDefaultRootPosition) ?? this._itemUtil.GetItem(ItemIDs.ContentRoot.ToString()));
        if (obj == null)
          return Guid.Empty;
        return obj.ID.ToGuid();
      }
    }

    private ManagerRoot GetCorrectManagerRootObject(Item rootItem)
    {
      return ManagerRoot.FromItem(rootItem);
    }
  }
```